# python3.8 youtube-dl

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I installed python3.8 in ubuntu  18.04 by compiling.
if I run  youtube-dl it says  cannot find python.
if I cat youtube-dl the  shebang line is  #!/usr/bin/python3
at terminal prompt python3 does get python3.8.
mohan@Shamoha:~$ python3
Python 3.8.0 (default, Nov 28 2019, 21:06:34) 
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > If I go to /usr/bin where python3.8 exists and run ./youtube-dl it runs but always says youtube said the video is unavailable even for videos I had downloaded before. How can I run youtube-dl from any directory?

Comment: re-install pip, then re-pip-install youtube-dl

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`python3 /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl`